# jquery keydown for only digits

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have an input box that is for payments, and i want to only allow number like x.xx, of course xxxx.x will work or xxxxx

i have the setup pretty much working minus some weird behavior. if the numbers 1 and 2 after the decimal can be 2 digits long (works) but if i press 3-9 then it only allows one of that digit. also 0's to the right of the decimal are being allowed infinitely.

heres what im working with. also i want to only allow the enter button and when its pressed then run a function

```
$('#money-button-input-box').keydown(function(event) {
    var str = $(this).val()

    if(str.length >= 1){
        var rightHalf = str.split('.')[1];
        if(rightHalf >= 3 && event.keyCode != 8 ){
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }

    if( (event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 110) && str.replace(/[^.]/g, "").length >= 1 ){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    allowOnlyNumbers(event);

    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        if($(this).val() == '')return;
        enterPayment($(this));
    }
});
```

and the function

```
function allowOnlyNumbers(events){
    // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, and enter
    if ( events.keyCode == 46 || events.keyCode == 8 || events.keyCode == 9 || events.keyCode == 27 || events.keyCode == 13 || 
    // allow decimals
    events.keyCode == 190 || events.keyCode == 110 || 
    // Allow: Ctrl+A
    (events.keyCode == 65 && events.ctrlKey === true) || 
    // Allow: home, end, left, right
    (events.keyCode >= 35 && events.keyCode <= 39)) {
    // let it happen, don't do anything
        return;
    } else {
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if (events.shiftKey || (events.keyCode < 48 || events.keyCode > 57) && (events.keyCode < 96 || events.keyCode > 105 )) {
            events.preventDefault(); 
        }   
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qxtnd/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem of decimals is because you are using

```
rightHalf >= 3
```

which evaluates the actual number & not it's length, because javascript type-casts it to a number for the comparison. What you want instead is the number of digits, try

```
rightHalf.toString().length >= 2
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Qxtnd/1/

**Edit**

As long as *rightHalf* is a string you can do:

```
rightHalf.length >= 2
```

if *rightHalf* was a number you would get an exception doing that.

Comment: Well since it is a string you can actually leave out the .toString() it was being type-cast to a number

Comment: rightHalf don't need the toString function because it was string.

Comment: everything works perfectly now. i also removed tostring as others said

Answer (score 0):

```
function isNumberKeyUp(event, obj, beforeLength, afterLength) {
    var text = document.getElementById(obj).value;
    var splitText = text.split('.');
    if (splitText.length > 1 && splitText[1].length > afterLength) {
        document.getElementById(obj).value = splitText[0] + "." + splitText[1].substring(0,2);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function isNumberKey(event, obj,beforeLength,afterLength) {
    var keyCode1 = event.keyCode;

    var keyCode = 0;
    if (keyCode1 == 0)
        keyCode = event.which;
    else {
        keyCode = keyCode1;
    }

    if ((keyCode >= 48 && keyCode <= 57) || keyCode == 46 || keyCode == 13 || keyCode == 27 || keyCode == 127 ) {
        var text = document.getElementById(obj).value;
        if (keyCode == 46 && keyCode1 == 0) {
            if (text.toString().indexOf(".") != -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        if (keyCode == 46) {
            if (text.toString().indexOf(".") != -1) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        var splitText = text.split('.');
        if (splitText[0].length >= beforeLength) {
            if (keyCode == 46 && text.toString().indexOf(".") == -1) {
                return true;
            } else if (text.toString().indexOf(".") != -1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        return GetDefault(event);
    }
    return true;
}

function GetDefault(event) {
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    if (keyCode == 0)
        keyCode = event.which;

    if (keyCode == 8 || keyCode == 9 || keyCode == 35 || keyCode == 36 || keyCode == 37 || keyCode == 38 || keyCode == 39 || keyCode == 40 || keyCode == 46 || keyCode == 118) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Below is the html to call this events

```
<input type="text" onkeyup="return isNumberKeyUp(event,'txtID',9,2);" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event,'txtID',9,2);" required="required"  id="txtID" maxlength="12" value="1.00" name="txtID">
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/Qxtnd/3/)**

```
rightHalf.length >= 2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    $('#money-button-input-box').keyup(function () {
        $(this).val(FormatNumber($(this).val()));

    });

function FormatNumber(val){
    var split = val.split('.');
    if (split.length>1) return OnlyNumbersAllowed(split[0])+'.'+OnlyNumbersAllowed(split[1]);
    else return OnlyNumbersAllowed(split[0]);
}

function OnlyNumbersAllowed(val){
 return val.replace(/\D/g, '');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qxtnd/7/
You could easly put this regex in any function, instead of writing what you have now.

Comment: i use the allowOnlyNumbers function in other places so ill keep what i have

Comment: @Kuraiinazuma Even now it doesn't work. You can't have more than 1 decimal point in a currency value & he only wanted 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Precastic and besides its much beter, bcs someone can just copy paste something.